# DRF models with unkown number of items to save in PostgreSQL

Tags: django-models, django-rest-framework

I am building an API that pulls data from Trello and posts them into our website. In order to save my boards, lists and cards, I made 3 different model classes with `name` and `id` both defined as `Charfield`, but I want to get the user's checklist, and the number of items are different for each user.

¿How to can I create a model that receives as many topics as my user wants to create?

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have solutions in Django such like: VectorFields, JSONFields, etc. But I rarely recommend this kind of solutions.

What I use in my case is a relation of ManyToMany between this two classes.

Suppose this.

```py
from django.db import models


class CheckList(models.Model):
   item_name = models.TextField()
   ...
   

class TrelloCard(models.Model):
   name = TextField()
   ...
   check_list = models.ManyToManyField(CheckList, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.PROTECT)

   ...
```

In JSON this relation will showed as:

```
{
 id:
 name:
 ...
 check_list: [
     id:
     item_name:
     ...   
 ]
}
```

Plus this solution will be perfect for working with the entire django-rest-framework, things such serialziers, filters, views, etc.

Comment: Thanks a lot, man. I'll try this and later I'll tell you if it worked, but thank you anyway!

Comment: It looks like that ManyToManyField doesn't accept on_delete parameter. I have only found it on ForeignKey class. But anyway, I discovered the topics that I need to study, and that helps a lot! Thanks again.

Comment: Oh Yeah, I miss this. The on_delete is for models.ForeignKey
Dont know why I put this on a ManyToMany. I will edit the answer.

Comment: Hey man, check this out. Consuming Trello's API I have multiple checklist itens inside a card. Each card is inside a list, each list is inside a board, that belongs to a user. Will I use foreign key for boards, lists and cards, and many-to-many for checklists?